# Decode Android CameraPreview bytes in C++ Server

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets, opencv

I am using this code to get the `CameraPreview` from my Android phone -

```
private Camera.PreviewCallback mPreviewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        synchronized (mQueue) {
            if (mQueue.size() == MAX_BUFFER) {
                mQueue.poll();
            }
            mQueue.add(data);
        }
    }
};
```

And this to send it to my C++ Server via `Sockets` -

```
mSocket = new Socket();
mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mIP, mPort), 10000);
BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
outputStream.write(mCameraPreview.getImageBuffer());
outputStream.flush();
```

I got these codes from [this](http://www.codepool.biz/making-android-smart-phone-a-remote-ip-camera.html) website, but the Server (my Windows PC) is coded in `C++`, and on the website the Server code is in `Java`. I want to decode the `CameraPreview` bytes and display them in my OpenCV window. I can receive the bytes, display them too, but I need help with converting the bytes to images. Can anyone help me with this?

**For those who don't want to visit the site for the Server Java codes, here is the code -**

> On the server side, use a buffer queue to cache incoming data:

```
public int fillBuffer(byte[] data, int off, int len, LinkedList<byte[]> YUVQueue) {
    mTotalLength += len;
    mByteArrayOutputStream.write(data, off, len);
    if (mTotalLength == mFrameLength) {
        synchronized (YUVQueue) {
            YUVQueue.add(mByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
            mByteArrayOutputStream.reset();
        }
        mTotalLength = 0;         
        System.out.println("received file");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Referring to StackOverflow, we can use the following code to decode the NV21 data:

```
public static int[] convertYUVtoRGB(byte[] yuv, int width, int height)
        throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {        
    int[] out = new int[width * height];
    int sz = width * height;

    int i, j;
    int Y, Cr = 0, Cb = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int pixPtr = j * width;
        final int jDiv2 = j >> 1;
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            Y = yuv[pixPtr];
            if (Y < 0)
                Y += 255;
            if ((i & 0x1) != 1) {
                final int cOff = sz + jDiv2 * width + (i >> 1) * 2;
                Cb = yuv[cOff];
                if (Cb < 0)
                    Cb += 127;
                else
                    Cb -= 128;
                Cr = yuv[cOff + 1];
                if (Cr < 0)
                    Cr += 127;
                else
                    Cr -= 128;
            }
            int R = Y + Cr + (Cr >> 2) + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 5);
            if (R < 0)
                R = 0;
            else if (R > 255)
                R = 255;
            int G = Y - (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 4) + (Cb >> 5) - (Cr >> 1)
                    + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 4) + (Cr >> 5);
            if (G < 0)
                G = 0;
            else if (G > 255)
                G = 255;
            int B = Y + Cb + (Cb >> 1) + (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 6);
            if (B < 0)
                B = 0;
            else if (B > 255)
                B = 255;
            out[pixPtr++] = 0xff000000 + (B << 16) + (G << 8) + R;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```